# Similar triangles and orthocenter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $\triangle ABC$ is an acute triangle. $AM$ $(M\in BC)$ and $BN$ $(N\in AC)$ are altitudes. If $CM:AC=1:3$, I should find $NM:AB$ and $CN:BC$.
> [image]

I was able to show that $\triangle AMC \sim BNC$. Therefore, $\dfrac{AM}{BN}=\dfrac{CM}{CN}=\dfrac{AC}{BC}$. From here we can get $\dfrac{CM}{AC}=\dfrac{CN}{BC}=\dfrac{1}{3}$. What should I do to find $NM:AB$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Hint:* Use angle chasing to show $\triangle CNM\sim \triangle CBA$.

Observe that since the quadrilateral $ABMN$ is cyclic, we have $$\angle MNC=180^\circ-\angle ANM=\beta$$ Similarity implies $$\frac{NM}{AB}=\frac{CM}{AC}=\frac13$$

Comment: Thank you for the response! Why $ABMN$ is cyclic?

Comment: The angle subtended by $AB$ is the same: $\angle ANB=\angle AMB=90^\circ$

Comment: Is $\angle ANB=\angle AMB=90^\circ$ enough to conclude that $ABMN$ is cyclic?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral#Characterizations)

Comment: I know that a convex quadrilateral ABCD is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles are supplementary. Don't know any other necessary and sufficient conditions. May you explain why this is true in this case?

Comment: Have a look at the next part

Comment: Diagonals? .....

Comment: Wikipedia reads: "Another necessary and sufficient condition for a convex quadrilateral ABCD to be cyclic is that an angle between a side and a diagonal is equal to the angle between the opposite side and the other diagonal." Now, in your case, the diagonals are $AM$ and $BN$, and the angle between one diagonal and a side $(90^\circ)$ is the same as the angle between the opposite side and the other diagonal

Comment: Yeah, but how can we show this?

Comment: I don't have enough place in the comments --and I can't attach images-- in order to develop that well-known Theorem further... you might want to ask another question ;)

Comment: I got it. I guess $\angle ABC=\beta$ in your solution, right?

Comment: Exactly, $\angle ABC=\beta$